# Picard group of the moduli space of semistable rank 2 parabolic vector bundles over smooth complex projective curves with trivial determinant

Tags: reference-request, moduli-spaces

I am looking for the **Picard group of the moduli space of semistable rank 2 parabolic vector bundles over smooth complex projective curves with trivial determinant**.

Having determinant trivial, I believe we can consider the bundles as parabolic $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$-bundles as well. The closest result have found in this regard is a paper by Laszlo and Sorger, *'The line bundles on the moduli of G-bundles on a curve'*, but they only talk about *quasi-parabolic* bundles rather than parabolic bundles.

My question is: Is the picard group known already? Does anyone know of any reference? 
I need it urgently if possible. Any help would be appreciable.